Getting "cannot schedule new futures after interpreter shutdown" error while using boto3.client download_file and upload_file functions
I am using boto3.client.download_file() and boto3.client.upload_file() functions, For python3.8 environment it's working fine, but after upgrading to python3.10, getting "RuntimeError: cannot schedule new futures after interpreter shutdown". I am using latest version of boto3 library. Tried with several other versions of the boto3 (1.18, 1.17, 1.26, latest 1.34), all other versions are giving same error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/awswrangler/s3/_fs.py", line 585, in open_s3_object
    yield s3obj
  File "/opt/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/awswrangler/s3/_upload.py", line 74, in upload
    s3_f.write(local_f.read())  # type: ignore[arg-type]
  File "/opt/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/awswrangler/s3/_fs.py", line 550, in write
    self.flush()
  File "/opt/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/awswrangler/s3/_fs.py", line 427, in flush
    self._upload_proxy.upload(
  File "/opt/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/awswrangler/s3/_fs.py", line 133, in upload
    future = self._exec.submit(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 169, in submit
    raise RuntimeError('cannot schedule new futures after '
RuntimeError: cannot schedule new futures after interpreter shutdown

One solution which I got while browsing this error was to disable the use of threads, it worked but we want to use the thread since our file size might go significantly big which will slowdown the download and upload process.
I also tried using thread.joins solution given in another similar question, but getting same error.
Another solution which I tried was by using awswrangler library  it is working fine when the file size is smaller but it starts to give the same error when I increase the file size.

I think people had same issue with python 3.9 and python 3.10. But, I donno why.

The boto3 maintainers shared a potential fix for this problem:

The most straight forward fix is to place this import at the top level process/thread so a reference is kept. That will avoid the shutdown issues that are being encountered.

from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

Source: https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/3113
